# PHP Erroring and displaying a white page?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to retrieve all data from my table where the user id is equal to X.

I have the following only I receive a blank white page as though there's an error in my syntax, can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
try {
 $uid = 3;
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', 'liam@', 'PW');
$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE user_id = :uid');
$data->bindValue(":uid", $uid);

foreach($data as $row) {
    print_r($row). '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Do you have [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/error_reporting) on (`E_ALL`)? What is in the `catch()` block? You are missing the `fetch` and `execute` part.

Comment: when you select the pdo tag, an info tab appears. it got infos. these will assuredly let you fix this code

Comment: Use `prepare()` instead of `query()`and you have no `execute()`.

Answer (score 1):

Missing the closing } for the try